# OData DateTimeOffset Filters returning dates outside of filters

Tags: odata

I am requesting data from a server that is using OData v4. I am using $filter to get specific items from a date/time range, but the server is returning items that don't fit within the filter.

The following addition to the URL: `?$filter=date(MyDate) ge 2023-08-26 and MyDate le 2023-08-30T23:59:59Z` returns objects with a `MyDate` of e.g. `2023-08-04T13:36:21Z`, which shouldn't be returned within the filters. In the first part of the filter, the `date()` function should return just the date part of the DateTimeOffset field of each record to compare with the Date given, and the second part of the filter is a comparison of two DateTimeOffset fields, and yet I am getting data from outside the filters.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!
Eddie